# How to get the sorted column value in datatable?

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I have a dataTable. I want to fire an event when the columns of the dataTable are sorted.
Here is my code.

```
var productTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "bFilter": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "aLengthMenu": [[-1, 25, 50, 100], ["All", 25, 50, 100]],
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bPaginate": true
});   
$('#example').bind('sort',   function () { /* Here I want to get the value of the sorted coumn */});
```

Inside the bind function I want the name of the sorted column. Can anyone help me to find this out?

Comment: haven't used the datatable plugin, but you can get the element on which the event was fired with `this`, or `$(this)` to convert it to a jquery object.

Comment: Already tried $(this), it give me the entire table.

Answer (score 2):

The sort event has two arguments.  The event and the datatable itself.  Using the datatable argument you can read the current aaSorting field and determine the index of the column sorting and the direction of the column sorting.  With the index of the column sorting you can look up the column and get the name of the column being sorted using the datatables aoColumns field.

```
.bind('sort', function (e, dt) {
    var direction = dt.aaSorting[0][1];
    var columnIndex = dt.aaSorting[0][0];
    var columnName = dt.aoColumns[columnIndex].sTitle;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting DataTable's API reference:

fnSortListener Attach a sort listener to an element for a given column

Input parameters:

```
{node}: the element to attach the sort listener to
{int}: the column that a click on this node will sort on
{function}: callback function when sort is run
```

Return parameter:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

  // Sort on column 1, when 'sorter' is clicked on
  oTable.fnSortListener( document.getElementById('sorter'), 1 );
} );
```

So, basically, you'll have to bind a listener to this event and you will get an **index** of a column. Then you'll have to look it's name up.